# Count number of groups with any certain value across rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to count the number of groups which have any `True` value across there rows in a column. Here I have some reproducible data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'group': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'condition': ["True", "False", "False", "True", "True", "False", "False", "False"]}
pd.DataFrame(data=df, index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Output:

```
   group condition
0      1      True
1      1     False
2      1     False
3      2      True
4      2      True
5      2     False
6      3     False
7      3     False
```

As we can see in group 1 and group 2 there are rows with a True value which means the result should be that there are 2 groups. So the expected outcome should look like this:

```
   groups  total_any_true
0       3               2
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to count the total number of groups that have any certain value across their rows?

Comment: The condition values are strings, not booleans?

Comment: Hi @Nick, yes they are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the peculiar format, the best is likely to craft the DataFrame manually:

```
out = pd.DataFrame([[df['group'].nunique(),
                     df['condition'].eq('True').groupby(df['group']).any().sum(),
                   ]], columns=['groups', 'total_any_true'])
```

Output:

```
   groups  total_any_true
0       3               2
```

Alternatively:

```
out = (df
   .assign(condition=df['condition'].eq('True'))
   .groupby('group', as_index=False).any()
   .agg({'group': 'nunique', 'condition': 'sum'})
   .to_frame().T
)
```

Output:

```
   group  condition
0      3          2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option :

```
out = (df.loc[df["condition"].eq("True"), ["group"]]
           .agg(["count", "nunique"]).set_axis(
                ["groups", "total_any_true"])
           .T.reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   groups  total_any_true
0       3               2
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

You can use `agg` directly on `df['group']`.

```
cond1 = df['condition'].eq('True')
df['group'].agg(groups=pd.Series.nunique, 
                total_any_true=lambda x: x.where(cond1).nunique())\
           .to_frame(0).T
```

output:

```
    groups  total_any_true
0   3       2
```